# API Gateway with Lambda returns 404 on first call when left idle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've built an API with API gateway and Lambda. I've noticed that when left idle (usually a few hours), it will fail on the **first** call. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Should I implement retries on my API calls or is there some configuration for Lambda that I am missing out on?

```
[INFO]  2019-04-15T03:18:58.263Z    SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded
```

This is the only line that was logged in CloudWatch for my Lambda function.

Comment: Please share the exact error string/stacktrace.

Comment: The 404 response is presumably coming from your Lambda function. Check the CloudWatch Logs from your Lambda and see if you can work out why your code is responding 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that AWS Lambda will take longer than usual to invoke a function if left idle due to [cold starts](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/a2v2h9/how_do_you_guys_work_around_aws_lambda_cold_starts/).

The error that I have received was due to the Lambda taking longer than my defined timeout for http requests to return a response.

I've removed VPC from my Lambda function as suggested to lower the cold start time and I have not experience any cold start issue with Lambda since.